# Ajax search pro advanced option - Combining custom fields with terms

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm using [**Ajax search pro**](https://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress-live-search-plugin/3357410) plugin with WooCommerce for advanced products search.

In [**Ajax search pro**](https://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress-live-search-plugin/3357410) plugin settings, there is a tab "Advanced options" where you can customize post title and post description.
For example if you search typing **`Aven...`** then result will shows **`Avengers`** …

In advanced tab you can Customize result show whith some custom field and get something like: **`Avengers 10$`** combining **`'post_title'`** with **`'_price`**'.

My problem is that I can't combine that custom fields with custom taxonomy. For example combining **'post_title'** custom field with **`release_year`** custom taxonomy isn't possible, to have something like this combination **Avengers 2012**.

I would like to use some special combinations between custom fields and:

- Custom taxonomy terms **`release_year`** like [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057798/display-only-the-first-and-last-term-of-taxonomy-for-a-product/39059332#39059332).
- Custom taxonomy type *(custom category type)* **`tvshow_cat`** *(similar as **`'product_cat'`** is)*. 
  I would like to display a string of first 3 related product terms (coma separated) from **`tvshow_cat`** taxonomy.

How can I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: i edited my Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can build a function that will copy related formatted taxonomy terms in product meta data custom fields. Here is the commented code:

1) The sub-functions (used by the 2 main functions):

```
// Processing 'release_year' formatting in a string

function process_release_year( $post_id ){

    $release_years_str = get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'release-year', '', ',' );
    $release_years_arr = explode(',', $release_years_str);
    $count = sizeof( $release_years_arr );
    $first_year = $release_years_arr[ 0 ];
    if ( $count > 1 ) {
        $last_year = $release_years_arr[ $count - 1 ];
        $releaseyear_as_text = ' (' . $first_year . ' - ' . $last_year . ')';
    }
    elseif ($count == 1) $releaseyear_as_text = ' ' . $first_year;
    else $releaseyear_as_text = '';

    return $releaseyear_as_text;
}


// Processing 'tvshow_cat' formatting in a string (3 coma separated terms in a string)

function process_tvshow_cat( $post_id ){
    $description_terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'tvshow_cat' );
    $count = 0; $description_string = '';
    foreach ( $description_terms as $description_term ) {
        $count++;
        if( $count < 4 ){
            $description_string .= $description_term;
            if( $count < 3 ) $description_string .= ', ';
        }
    }
    return $description_string;
}


// The two custom fields creation mechanism

function custom_fields_creation( $post_id ){

    // The release year
    $test_cf1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'release_year', true );
    if( empty($test_cf1) ) {
        // if doesn't exist we create it
        $release_year = process_release_year($post_id);
        if( !empty( $release_year ) )
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'release_year', $release_year );
    }

    // The TV show cat
    $test_cf2 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mov_description', true );
    if( empty($test_cf2) ) {
        // if doesn't exist we create it
        $description_mov = process_release_year($post_id);
        if( !empty($description_mov) )
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'mov_description', $description_mov );
    }
}
```

Here is a function **to be used only once** (make a database backup before). This function will create **for all existing products** that 2 special custom fields.

```
// 1. FOR ALL EXISTING PRODUCTS ==> ==> ==> USE IT ONE TIME ONLY!
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'product_custom_fields_bulk_action' ); // To stop it, just comment this line
function product_custom_fields_bulk_action(){

    // Get all published products
    $products = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1
    ) );

    // Iterating each product
    foreach( $products as $product )
        custom_fields_creation( $product->id );
}
```

The function below, will create that custom field **each time a new product is published**:

```
// 2. FOR "NEW CREATED" AND PUBLISHED PRODUCT
add_action('transition_post_status', 'product_custom_fields_action', 10, 3);
function product_custom_fields_action($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if( $old_status != 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' && !empty($post_id) && in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'product') ) )
        custom_fields_creation( $post->ID );
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file in your active child theme or theme…*

You can clone as many custom fields you want...

**This code is tested and works.**